# What's the reasoning behind the design of the TLS 1.2 PRF?

Tags: tls, key-derivation

TLS 1.2 defines a PRF-like construction $P_{hash} : \{0,1\}^* \times \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^l$ for key derivation, etc. To quote the spec:

> We define a data expansion function, `P_hash(secret, data)`,
>   that uses a single hash function to expand a secret and seed into an
>   arbitrary quantity of output:
>
> ```
> P_hash(secret, seed) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(1) + seed) +
>                        HMAC_hash(secret, A(2) + seed) +
>                        HMAC_hash(secret, A(3) + seed) + ...
> ```
>
> where `+` indicates concatenation.
>
> `A()` is defined as:
>
> ```
> A(0) = seed
> A(i) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(i-1))
> ```

Why does $P_{hash}$ invoke HMAC twice per block of output? Are there valid security arguments for doing so?

In particular, why not a simpler, faster, counter-based scheme such as:

> $P_{hash}(\text{secret}, \text{seed}) = B(\text{secret},\text{seed},0) \| B(\text{secret},\text{seed},1) \| \dots
> \\ B(\text{secret},\text{seed},i) = \text{HMAC}_{hash}(\text{secret}, \text{to_byte}(i) \| \text{seed})$

If there is no technical advantage, what are the historical reasons behind this design?

Comment: If TLS were designed today, we'd probably use [HKDF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869) instead.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It *is* being designed today, and it uses HKDF. As you well know, I suspect :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes not so sure I'd call it being "designed" so much as monkey-patched. Some of the decisions for 1.3 aren't going near far enough. Still _way_ too many options in there. IMHO there should be exactly two cipher suites, and everything else is either a MUST or is completely out of the spec. Or is there a TLS 2.0 WG coming up with something simpler that can actually be implemented securely and analyzed?

Comment: @rmalayter A TLS that will be implemented securely? Dream on ;)

Comment: @rmalayter You may be interested in my answer to the question [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37129/what-kind-of-custom-header-add-to-encrypted-file-to-identify-my-encryption-consi/37131#37131). I think you'll find that we kind-of agree on this. As for this question, it might be that the reasons are lost in the mist of time.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm not sure if I can reach you this way, but you might have an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [Marsh Ray](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg10584.html)'s analysis. PRF in TLS is designed to be the most conservative aspect of TLS (the last part of TLS to break). Mr. Marsh calls it *"the slowest, most conservatively designed stream cipher in common use"*.

TLS PRF seems to be NIST [sp800_108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf) in "Double Pipeline Mode". What Tim McLean contemplates above as a potential alternative is sp800_108 in "Counter" mode.

The "Double Pipeline Mode" is the most conservative sp800_108 mode, and is also subject to several papers (ex. by Koutarou Suzuki and Kan Yasuda) that prove certain "feel-good" properties about it that are not present in other modes.

TLS (IMHO) is trying to ensure that its PRF survives even when the underlying hash function gets utterly broken (ex. assume something even more broken than MD5).

Comment: The other thing to note is that, of the components within TLS, the PRF is probably the least performance critical - virtually all your time is spent doing something else.  Hence, it makes sense to be ultra-conservative with the PRF, as it doesn't cost you (that is, slow down the protocol) that much.